# Touchpad not working in gnome on wayland

Tags: fedora, gnome, touchpad

I am using Gnome desktop with wayland on fedora 37 with kernel version and arch `6.1.6-200.fc37.x86_64`.

Touchpad suddenly stopped working after booting the system, it was previously working.

```
$ libinput list-devices
....

Device:           MSFT0001:01 04F3:3186 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event14
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             100x66mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Disable-w-trackpointing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

....
```

I have enabled the touchpad in gnome settings, but still it is not working.

I tested on various desktop environments but the touchpad is enabled everywhere and still is not working, the device itself is working (checked in windows).

I tried every possible solution but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

While self (laptop Ubuntu 20.04) does NOT know how this works when my mouse just stops moving, most times (70%?) when I do below mouse re-starts working again.

BTW on some occasions it just does nothing, most times it re-starts, if tried 5 times without success...  command on terminal to **re-boot** while I take a short break...

sudo fwupdtool get-devices

```
Using above command re-started my dead mouse
```

The fwupdmgr is a tool that allows an administrator to query and control
the fwupd daemon, allowing them to perform actions such as installing or
downgrading firmware.